# How do I convert a excel file in to this format in python?

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas, dictionary

I have an excel file with two column and I would like to convert it to this format

```
l = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
     {'a': 4, 'b': 3}]
```

a : refers to the first column header and b refers to the second column header.

I imported the excel file using Pandas as

```
dataframe = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
```

I tried by creating empty list and set data frame to that empty list but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel sheet has strictly two columns with values in every cell within the columns,

You can save it as a .csv file and parse it as such:

```
results = []
with open("your-file.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        separated = line.split(',')
        results.append( { 'a':separated[0], 'b':separated[1] } )
```

Comment: Do you really need to save the file as csv?

Comment: @mad_ If you want this method to work, then yes, a copy of the excel sheet must be saved as a `.csv`. I prefer doing things this way because it requires less libraries and is simpler for me to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dataframe into dict

```
dataframe = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
dataframe.to_dict('records')
```